# Why JQuery libraries don't work when I use them in React build compilation

Tags: reactjs, mern, npm-scripts

I need help to understand this, I hope someone can give me a guide of what to do.

I'm using some external jquery libraries in my public/index.html file, for example:

```
<script
      src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/otherjs/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
    ></script>
```

They work when I'm in dev mode, but when I run npm run build the website doesn't work because all the acctions on this files are not loading, even if I refresh the page.

Thanks, let me know if you need more info to understand the issue.

Comment: This seems to be an issue with your webpack configuration, could you please add this?

Comment: I didn't use a webpack file, I used create-react-app. Where do I get the webpack config you want, the one in the node_modules folder?

Comment: Then it is made for you, and you probably don't want to touch it. In CRA you can add `import "jquery";` to the top of your main js file and `npm i jquery` to have it bundled with your javascript.

Comment: So, I'm new with React, sorry for this question, when you say the main, it will be index.js or App.js?

Comment: Either is usually good in CRA, since both are loaded but I would put it in `index.js` since that is your entrypoint for JS.

Comment: Cool, I’ll test it and let you know. Thanks man

Comment: No, it didn't work. I try to use ```import "jquery"``` and ```import $ from "jquery"```

Comment: What is the built HTML file, maybe you can manually edit the script tag manually to reference the correct file (this also gives a better understanding of what PUBLIC_URL is defined as for you)?

Comment: The file is being called by the index.html, I see it when I inspect in Chrome.

Comment: Does it get a 404, or does it correctly load all the files?

Comment: Yes, is loaded, the same as when I run dev.

Comment: Then it probably isn't a problem with jQuery, but rather another issue, how are you serving the files?

Comment: As I explained in this post, I added the script tag to the index.html, and it works in dev mode perfectly

Comment: I meant serving in built/prod mode, maybe the issue is the serving of the built files isn't picking something up/serving the wrong files. (Basically if you are using `http-server` or similar), Since you can't open the files directly, as well as maybe the files are on a wrong path, etc.

Comment: I don’t know, I added the files in dev mode to index.html and then just ran npm run build, I thought it was the same thing. Maybe I shoud do something else but that’s what I don’t know.

Comment: Can use the instructions from npm build or https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment and reply if that works and then go to localhost:5000 (or whatever port serve gives you). Otherwise it will not load files correctly.

Comment: They don’t work even using this deployment options.